# Error enabling RDMA on Windows Server 2012 via Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, vmware-esx

I am trying to enable RDMA on a virtual Windows 2012 server. I have tried the following commands but I keep getting an error.

```
Enable-NetAdapterRdma -Name "Ethernet"
```

And

```
Set-NetAdapterRdma -Name "Ethernet" -Enabled $True
```

The first command returns 
Enable-NetAdapterRdma : No MSFT_NetAdapterSettingData objects found with property 'Name' equal to 'Ethernet'

The second command returns the same thing. I know the name is correct because I used that same name to enable RSS. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Does the NIC actually support RDMA? This output usually means lack of RDMA support at the hardware level.

If this is a virtual NIC in a VMware VM, you should use a PVRDMA virtual adapter; also, the ESXi host should have RDMA-capable NICs and they must be properly configured.

Some relevant docs:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-347B822E-5324-4DB3-A228-1F6A7AA871D2.html
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-B3776418-86AF-448D-B814-FDA4EFB6A34E.html#GUID-B3776418-86AF-448D-B814-FDA4EFB6A34E

Comment: Upon further investigation, I believe that you are correct in that the support isn't there for it. When I look at the advanced adapter settings there is no entry for RDMA. I believe that is the answer to my question.

Comment: @JimMiller could you, please specify what NIC is used?

Comment: It's virtual. Vmxnet3 is the type

Comment: @JimMiller as stated in the first article I linked, in order to use virtual RDMA you need to use PVRDMA virtual network adapters; this also needs to be supported and properly configured in the host, but the virtual NIC *has* to be PVRDMA; vmxnet3 just can't do that.

Comment: @massimo thank you. That answers my question. Because of our solutions architect specifications I am restricted to vmxnet3 so I will need to tell the client RDMA is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your command you will want to call for the -InterfaceAlias.

Your Command:

`Enable-NetAdapterRdma -Name "Ethernet"`

Change to Command:

`Enable-NetAdapterRdma -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet"`

You can use `Get-NetAdapter -AddressFamily IPv4` to view your adapters InterfaceAlias names.